# Switching between flash and iframe version of live streaming Ustream with javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, flash, iframe

I'm tryng to make a button for switching between  flash version and iframe version of a ustream live channel that i have embed in my personal site

flash code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="640" height="392" id="utv786564"><param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false&amp;brand=embed&amp;cid=3064708"/><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/><param name="movie" value="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf"/><embed flashvars="autoplay=false&amp;brand=embed&amp;cid=3064708" width="640" height="392" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" id="utv786564" name="utv_n_665786" src="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></object>
```

iframe code:

```
<iframe width="640" height="392" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/3064708?v=3&amp;wmode=direct" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px none transparent;">    </iframe>
<br /><a href="http://www.ustream.tv" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;" target="_blank">Broadcast live streaming video on Ustream</a>
```

For this scope i'm using following code:

javascript:

```
var newHTML = 'html2';
var oldHTML = document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML;

function changeText3(){  
    var currentHTML = document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML;
if (currentHTML!=newHTML) 
       {
     document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML = newHTML;
}
else
  {
document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML = oldHTML;
}
}
```

html:

```
<div id='divtabone'>html1</div>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText3()' value='change Html'/>
```

replacing html1 and html2 with flash and iframe code reported above

working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/nqj2L07j/2/

I have inserted this code in my test site wordpress:

http://www.grigione.5gbfree.com/test/

but how can see when i click change html button i can change video from flash version to iframe version one time only because if i reclick 
and i want return to flash version it remain in iframe version
i have made a demo with codes here:

https://jsfiddle.net/z36e77ru/1/

the code that i have inserted in functions.php file of wordpress is following:

```
function mia_on_load_script()
{
    // Not our page, do nothing
    if( !is_page( 'test' ) )
        return;
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
var newHTML = '<div id="1" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 640px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><iframe width="640" height="392" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/3064708?v=3&amp;wmode=direct" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px none transparent;"></iframe></div><div id="2" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 320px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><iframe style="border: 0 none transparent;" src="//www.ustream.tv/socialstream/3064708" width="320" height="392" frameborder="no"></iframe></div>';
var oldHTML = document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML;

function changeText3(){  
    var currentHTML = document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML;
if (currentHTML!=newHTML) 
       {
     document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML = newHTML;
}
else
  {
document.getElementById('divtabone').innerHTML = oldHTML;
}
}
</script>


    <?php   
    };        
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mia_on_load_script' );

?>
```

html in page http://www.grigione.5gbfree.com/test/ :

```
<div id="divtabone"><div id="1" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 640px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="640" height="360" id="utv786564"><param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false&amp;brand=embed&amp;cid=3064708"/><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/><param name="movie" value="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf"/><embed flashvars="autoplay=false&amp;brand=embed&amp;cid=3064708" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" id="utv786564" name="utv_n_665786" src="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></object></div> <div id="2" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 320px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><iframe style="border: 0 none transparent;" src="//www.ustream.tv/socialstream/3064708" width="320" height="392" frameborder="no"></iframe></div></div>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText3()' value='click to change'/>
```

Why in wordpress don't work ? Cold be a problem of caching? Any other solution to resolve problem?
thanks

Comment: Before answering your question, why you want to switch between Flash and an iframe containing Flash ?!

Comment: i want make a button for users that have problems to view flash streaming clicking it they can swith to iframe version and users that don't want frame version can swith to flash version

Comment: But the iframe is showing Flash also ! So I don't see why I will ( as user ) switch from Flash to Flash ?

Comment: i have seen that mobile users if flash version is embed in site don't see streaming so i want give the possibilty to this users to swith at frame version

Comment: In that case ( the iframe is auto-switching between Flash and HTML5 version ) you don't event need to use your Flash version, the iframe is enough because it will do the job for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi So I had another look into your Problem. What happens if you try it this way?

Try this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nqj2L07j/6/

```
var flash = '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="640" height="392" id="utv786564"><param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false&amp;brand=embed&amp;cid=3064708"/><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/><param name="movie" value="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf"/><embed flashvars="autoplay=false&amp;brand=embed&amp;cid=3064708" width="640" height="392" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" id="utv786564" name="utv_n_665786" src="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></object>';
var iframe = '<iframe width="640" height="392" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/3064708?v=3&amp;wmode=direct" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px none transparent;">    </iframe><br /><a href="http://www.ustream.tv" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;" target="_blank">Broadcast live streaming video on Ustream</a>';
var is_flash = true;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        if (is_flash) {
            $('#divtabone').html(iframe);
            is_flash = false;
        } else {
            $('#divtabone').html(flash);
            is_flash = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you make a working demo on jsfiddle? I need of a only button

Comment: did an edit of my post. providing a fiddle you should try. let me know of your results.